# How to pass list of columns or * (all columns) to dynamic SQL query with psycopg2.sql

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using psycopg2.sql to generate query strings dynamically.

I want to be able to pass either a list of columns or an * (for all columns) to the same SELECT query string dynamically.

This works for a list of columns:

```
qry = sql.SQL('SELECT {} FROM {}.{}').format(
    sql.SQL(",").join(map(sql.Identifier, ["col1","col2"])),
    sql.Identifier('schema'),
    sql.Identifier('table'))
```

But this doesn't work when trying to select all columns:

```
qry = sql.SQL('SELECT {} FROM {}.{}').format(
    sql.Identifier('*')),
    sql.Identifier('schema'),
    sql.Identifier('table'))
```

The error I receive is "DatabaseError:  Execution failed on sql … column "*" does not exist"

Comment: Well, not sure if it's possible but what difference does it make to you if you simply use `*`  within the sql string rather than using an identifier

Comment: Difference is I want to use the same general query string 'SELECT {} FROM {}.{}' repeatedly within a function but with the option of selecting all columns, one column or a specific list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sql.Identifier('*')` generates `"*"`:

```
SELECT "*" FROM "schema"."table"
```

Use the basic [SQL Composable](http://psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.SQL):

```
qry = sql.SQL('SELECT {} FROM {}.{}').format(
    sql.SQL('*'),
    sql.Identifier('schema'),
    sql.Identifier('table'))
```

to get

```
SELECT * FROM "schema"."table"
```

Comment: Ok this explains the issue, thank you.  So I guess I can't use the same general SQL string and will instead need to use an if clause in my function to first test whether the variable passed to it requires a SQL Composable (in the case of "*") or a SQL Identifier (in the case of a list of column names)

Comment: Yes, there is no way to use the same (unconditional) expression in both cases.